# How to sum the properties of an object in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've got an object with properties and i want to calculate the time spent and total cost of all the items in the object.

```
[{giftFor: "Adrian", giftName: "mug", timeSpentOn: 20, cost: 6},
{giftFor: "Tanaka", giftName: "baseball", timeSpentOn: 17, cost: 45},
{giftFor: "Jimmy", giftName: "watch", timeSpentOn: 23, cost: 35},
{giftFor: "Brian", giftName: "diary", timeSpentOn: 8, cost: 43},
{giftFor: "Bob", giftName: "jeans", timeSpentOn: 13, cost: 32}]
```

I tried the method below but i got the error, "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'ExpensesBreakDown'."

```
   calculateExpenses(itemArray: ExpensesBreakDown ) {
    let cost: number = itemArray
        .map((a) => a.cost)
        .reduce(function (a, b) {
            return a + b;
        });
}
```

I defined Expensesbreakdown as a class

```
class ExpensesBreakDown {
    giftFor: string;
    giftName: string;
    timeSpentOn: number;
    cost: number;
}
```

How can i go about this? I've just started on software development and Angular so please correct my rookie mistakes

Comment: Show `ExpensesBreakDown` type/interface definition

Comment: I guess it should be `itemArray: ExpensesBreakDown[]` at least

Comment: If you expect `itemArray` to be an array, declare it as such.

Comment: You're missing the second argument to `reduce`.

Comment: ...which is not *required*, but *recommended*, to make it work with an empty array.

Comment: I've got a class  ExpensesBreakDown {
    giftFor: string;
    giftName: string;
    timeSpentOn: number;
    cost: number;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your parameter is an array then you should always end your interface with "[]". The correct code will be like this-

```
calculateExpenses(itemArray: ExpensesBreakDown[] ) {
    let cost: number = itemArray
        .reduce(function (a, b) {
            return a + b.cost;
        }, 0);
}
```

I have one suggestion, when you want to calculate more than one value, like in your case you want to calculate both timeSpentOn and cost, then you should use forEach loop then its time complexity will be O(n).

Comment: mapping is pointless. should be only done with .reduce

Comment: I have edited my response but the problem was the typescript error that needed to be solved. The question was not about having the best algorithm to get the sum.

Comment: Here is some point payment for correcting it :)

Answer (score 1):

No need for any fancy TypeScript feature. You can simply use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to sum the `cost` of each array element:

```js
const totalCost = [{
    giftFor: "Adrian",
    giftName: "mug",
    timeSpentOn: 20,
    cost: 6
  },
  {
    giftFor: "Tanaka",
    giftName: "baseball",
    timeSpentOn: 17,
    cost: 45
  },
  {
    giftFor: "Jimmy",
    giftName: "watch",
    timeSpentOn: 23,
    cost: 35
  },
  {
    giftFor: "Brian",
    giftName: "diary",
    timeSpentOn: 8,
    cost: 43
  },
  {
    giftFor: "Bob",
    giftName: "jeans",
    timeSpentOn: 13,
    cost: 32
  }
].reduce((sum, el) => sum += el.cost, 0);

console.log(`Total cost: $${totalCost}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const obj = [{giftFor: "Adrian", giftName: "mug", timeSpentOn: 20, cost: 6},
{giftFor: "Tanaka", giftName: "baseball", timeSpentOn: 17, cost: 45},
{giftFor: "Jimmy", giftName: "watch", timeSpentOn: 23, cost: 35},
{giftFor: "Brian", giftName: "diary", timeSpentOn: 8, cost: 43},
{giftFor: "Bob", giftName: "jeans", timeSpentOn: 13, cost: 32}]

const result = obj.reduce((acc, val) => ({ timeSpentOn: acc.timeSpentOn + val.timeSpentOn, cost: acc.cost + val.cost}), {timeSpentOn: 0, cost: 0})
```